# Only run code on a certain server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote a stored procedure to transfer data from one SQL server to another. Is it possible to have logic at the beginning of the stored procedure to only execute on a certain server?

For example:

```
If IP!="100.xxx.xxx.xxx" then
   RaiseError 'You cannot run this procedure from this server
end if
```

I know one solution is not deploy the proc to the other server. Just curious, thanks.
G-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF UPPER(@@SERVERNAME) = 'YOUR_SERVER'
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```

Note that `@@SERVERNAME` may include the instance name information. So you can also say:

```
IF UPPER(@@SERVERNAME) = 'YOUR_SERVER\YOUR_INSTANCE'
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```

If you only care about the server (and any instance on that server), you can use a different property, though this returns the node name not the virtual server name in the case of a clustered instance:

```
IF UPPER(SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')) = 'YOUR_SERVER'
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```

If it's clustered and you want the same code to prevent execution except on any instance in that cluster you can say:

```
IF UPPER(@@SERVERNAME) = 'YOUR_SERVER'
  OR UPPER(@@SERVERNAME) LIKE 'YOUR_SERVER\%'
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```